# Multiple extension in opne file dialog?

Tags: c#, winforms

How to set multiple extension in Open File Dialog. For example i want to load an image file. So, OpenFileDialog should filter all image file.

```
dlg.Filter = "Image File|*.jpg";
```

But, It should be displayed all image files. ie. jpeg, bmp, tif, gif, png, etc. How do i do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
dlg.Filter = "JPG|*.jpg|PNG|*.png|BMP|*.bmp";
```

If you want to  combine all extensions use `semicolon` between extensions like this:

```
dlg.Filter = "Image Files|*.jpg;*.bmp;*.png";
```

Here is the documentation for reference: [`OpenFileDialog.Filter Property`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.openfiledialog.filter%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: I know this but it displays single extension at a time. I have to change extension from the filter combo. I want to show all images in a single filter. like All Images then it should be displayed all type of images in open file dialog.

Comment: @danta  I have just added that version :) see my update

Answer (score 0):

dlg.Filter = "Image File|*.jpg,*.png|JPEG Files|*.jpg|PNG Files|*.png";